# How can I replace paragraph elements with new lines using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm currently using a regular expression to convert a textarea value's new lines to `<p>` tags, this newly formatted block of text is then inserted on the page and it's working fine. The block of text can be re-edited though, i.e. putting the block of text back in to the textarea for editing. Is there a regular expression I can use to replace the `<p>` tags with new lines again, so that the spacing is preserved as they're editing the text within the textarea?

(This is to be used with JavaScript / jQuery).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you leverage jQuery's queries to get the contents of each `<p>`, and then join them with `\n`:

```
function getTexts(selector) {
  var textContents = $(selector).map(function(i, item) {
    return $(item).text();
  });

  return textContents.join("\n\n");
}

$("#theTextarea").val(getTexts("#someContainer > p"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regex you could iterate over each `p` element, extract the text and build a string with each `p`'s text + a newline character.

```
var html = $('<div>' + text + '</div>');
var plain = '';

$(html.find('p')).each(function() {
    plain += '\n' + $(this).text();
});
```